# IFFT and convolution for time response

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, convolution, sampling

I am writting code to simulate a simple high speed transmission chain which has the following shape :

TX(PRBS with LFSR) -> Channel (Touchstone file format) -> RX (with CTLE)

I would like to get the time response at different moment :

- TX output
- RX input
- RX output

For the TX output, it's OK.

For the RX input, I have the time response of the signal (Time domain - Ts=2.5e-10 Samples=240) and I also have the channel transfer function (Frequency domain - df=1e7; Samples=1701) which I have transposed in the time domain by IFFT.

I did a convolution between the signal and the channel IFFT but, in vizualizing the time response, the result is wrong. Before the convolution, I also resampled the signal in order to get the same length of the channel ifft result(from 240 to 1701).

**How do I have to scale both signal and channel ifft in order to get a proper convolution and plot the right time response ? Do I have to put the same sampling rate before making the convolution ?**

Thank you very much.